# How to make MapServer WMS URL shorter?

Tags: mapserver, apache, ms4w

I got an Apache and MapServer bundle (MS4W). On MapServer I made a WMS service and connect it to clients (Leaflet, QGIS etc.) with an URL like this:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/ms4w/apps/example/polt.map
```

In MapServer documentation I found that Apache can convert this URL in something like this:

```
http://localhost/mywms
```

In  `httpd.conf` I see that rewrite module is on

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Also I had added this block

```
<Directory C:\ms4w\apps\htdocs>
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

After I created `.htaccess` file in `C:\ms4w\apps\htdocs`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule wmsmap?(.*) /cgi-bin/mapserv?map=C:/ms4w/apps/example/polt.map&$1
```

After I restarted Apache. But when I try to open with URL

```
http://localhost/wmsmap?layer=Green&mode=map
```

I got

```
The requested URL /wmsmap was not found on this server.
```

Where is my mistake?

**UPDATE**

I had removed `Directory` block what I added in `httpd.conf` file. And edit default block so I got:

```
<Directory "/ms4w/Apache/htdocs">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  #Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After I put `.htaccess` file in `/ms4w/Apache/htdocs`.
And now I got another error on same URL:

```
msSaveImage(): Unable to access file. Failed to create output file (/tmp/WMS15201604824704.png).
```

What permission do I need?

Comment: @JGH oh, sorry. Just a typo in copypaste.

Comment: Mode=map& doesn't give you a WMS response

Comment: Windows needs modify access to what ever folder location you have mapped as /tmp.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, but I don't know how to use `.htaccess` file too.

```
Alias /wmsmap "d:/ms4w/Apache/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe"
<Location /wmsmap >
   SetHandler cgi-script
   Options ExecCGI
   SetEnv MS_MAPFILE "d:/ms4w/apps/cgi-viewer/map/wmsdemo1.map"
</Location>
```

Comment: .htaccess settings don't affect the mapping

Answer (score 0):

Just create an alias on Apache. Like so:

```
<VirtualHost *> 
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mjp

Alias /ncn "/var/www/html/ncn"

<Directory "/var/www/html/ncn">
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```